# SQL join on subquery with condition issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm struggling when running a query on SQL. I need to strip the last 3 chars from a field that I have already created in my subquery and then join based upon that new field. The validation fails on line 5 "invalid column name 'PCD'."

```
SELECT 
    *, LEFT(SUBQUERY.PC,Len(SUBQUERY.PC) -3) AS PCD 
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         PI.ClientPostcode, PI.casekey, 
         REPLACE( PI.ClientPostcode ,' ', '') As PC
     FROM PI
     WHERE LEN(PI.ClientPostcode) >= 5) AS SUBQUERY 
INNER JOIN 
     [Postcodes] On outcode = PCD
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use the alias on the same level you defined.

```
SELECT *, 
       LEFT(SUBQUERY.pc, Len(SUBQUERY.pc) - 3) AS PCD 
FROM   (SELECT pi.clientpostcode, 
               pi.casekey, 
               Replace(pi.clientpostcode, ' ', '') AS PC 
        FROM   pi 
        WHERE  Len(pi.clientpostcode) >= 5) AS SUBQUERY 
INNER JOIN [postcodes] 
       ON outcode = LEFT(SUBQUERY.pc, Len(SUBQUERY.pc) - 3) 
                    ^^^^ dont use the alias
```

Or you use it in a subquery like this

```
SELECT *
FROM  ( 
        SELECT *, 
               LEFT(SUBQUERY.pc, Len(SUBQUERY.pc) - 3) AS PCD 
        FROM   (SELECT pi.clientpostcode, 
                       pi.casekey, 
                       Replace(pi.clientpostcode, ' ', '') AS PC 
                FROM   pi 
                WHERE  Len(pi.clientpostcode) >= 5) AS SUBQUERY 
      ) other_subq
INNER JOIN [postcodes] 
        ON outcode = other_subq.PCD
```